# Ошибка на Ununtu 22.04

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, closedxml

Добрый день получаю ошибку на Ubuntu 22.04

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
  Connection id "0HN0SO5TNVF9N", Request id "0HN0SO5TNVF9N:00000002": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
  System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Gdip' threw an exception.
   ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'libdl' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: liblibdl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
     at Interop.Libdl.dlopen(String fileName, Int32 flag)
     at System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.LoadNativeLibrary()
     at System.Drawing.SafeNativeMethods.Gdip..cctor()
```

Данная ошибка возникает только на ubuntu 22.04. Связана она с библиотекой closedxml и картинками в шаблоне excel.

Я попробовал уже

Установить эту библиотеку

sudo apt-get update && apt-get install -y libgdiplus

включил поддержку Unix

```
<ItemGroup>
        <RuntimeHostConfigurationOption Include="System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport" Value="true" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Так же попробовал установить LibreOffice, но ничего не помогает. Как это исправить?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libc6-dev` на версии 22+ нет больше библиотеки `libdl` по умолчанию

Comment: @evo Это не решило проблемы((

Comment: Решил проблему. Если используете ubuntu >= 22.

1. Обновите closedXml минимум до 0.97 версии
2.  sudo apt-get install -y --allow-unauthenticated libgdiplus libc6-dev libx11-dev
3. <ItemGroup>
        <RuntimeHostConfigurationOption Include="System.Drawing.EnableUnixSupport" Value="true" />
</ItemGroup>

Comment: Я думаю указанную проблему в вопросе это решило, но остальные возможно и нет